# pushing button will call a number table view

Tags: ios, button, call

I have a tableview controller and that is connected to a detailviewcontroller.
I my detailviewcontroller, I have a image a title a description and 4 buttons.

I want the 4 buttons to call 4 separate numbers.
button name call1, call2, call3, call4.

at the moment i have this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    _TitleLabel.text = _DetailModal[0];
    _DescriptionLabel.text = _DetailModal[1];
    _ImageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:_DetailModal[2]];

    self.navigationItem.title = _DetailModal[0];

    if ([_TitleLabel.text isEqualToString:@"alex"]) {


    }
```

//so the the names are stored in `_TitleLabel`, so if Alex is chosen from the tableviewcontroller. I want the 4 buttons in the detailviewcontoller to be call buttons. So I have to be able to give the 4 buttons separate tel numbers.

Can some one please help

Comment: OSX or iOS?  (please remove xcode tag and set the correct platform tag).

Comment: Please, name your var starting with a lower case.

Comment: this is for iOS  @trojanfoe